# How to resolve improper date of birth data

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, data-cleaning, data-processing

My dataset contains incorrect date of birth entries. How do I resolve this?,since this data is important to my analysis as it will help in segmentation. E.g: a customer has a date of birth entry of 1843-12-21, which is clearly not proper. Similar issues are also present.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: need sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to deal with it:

1. Try to understand the reason of the error. Maybe in some cases people input data in the wrong fields.
2. Make an educated guess - for example 1843 could be 1943.
3. Consider these errors to be missing values.